# Wordpress - single-<custom type>.php showing multiple results

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I've created a custom post type using `register_post_type( 'gallery' , $args );`, setting the capability_type to 'post'.

I've then created single-gallery.php to display this data.

Within single-gallery.php I have put the following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="galleryShow">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      echo(get_the_ID());
      echo($post->post_title);
      the_content();
    endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As I understand it this should show the details of the currently selected 'gallery' page?  However it's showing the ID, title and content for EVERY gallery page.

Should I create single-gallery.php and have everything 'out' of the loop rather than 'in the loop' as I have done?  If so how would I get only the selected pages ID outside the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem - the single-gallery file should be used when you view a *single* post of type 'gallery'. You can test this most effectively by hitting 'preview' within the edit screen for a gallery post. If you're seeing multiple posts on the screen that comes up, then there's another problem.

Comment: Just checked 'preview' and it's still showing every post of type gallery, whereas I want only the single chosen post of type gallery.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: not a wordpress guru but a quick-fix hack would be to drop "while (have_posts())" and the "endwhile;" statements. Not sure as to the full ramifications but you wouldn't loop through entries then

Comment: @Don - I tried that but then I only get the content of the same 'Gallery' post, regardless of which gallery post i'm actually on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my site to Wordpress 3.1 and it seems to have resolved this issue.